# Flask SQLAlchemy autoincrement without using primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to use the autoincrement option on the field id in SQLAlchemy without setting the column as a primary key. Something like that:

```
class CaseModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'case'

unique_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
id = db.Column(db.Integer(), autoincrement=True)
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using hybrid property:

```
class CaseModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'case'
    CURRENT_ID_VALUE = 1

    unique_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    _id = db.Column(db.Integer())

    @hybrid_property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, _):
        self._id = CaseModel.CURRENT_ID_VALUE
        CaseModel.CURRENT_ID_VALUE += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your suggestion but it did not work.

Comment: Well, I haven't tested this solution, you can try to make CURRENT_ID_VALUE global or store it somewhere and use it in your Model

Comment: The main idea is to use hybrid property for any custom behavior on get/set operations